# Can't use std::vector in place of std::array on QOpenGLBuffer::allocate

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm working with OpenGl with Qt and I'm allocating a buffer with std::array, I want to replace it with std::vector, it should work almost the same way, but it doesn't work at all, just black screen.

Vertex is just a class with six floats (x,y,z, r,g,b) and few methods

declaration of vertexes

```cpp
//works
std::array<Vertex, 12> vertexes = {
    VERTEX_0, VERTEX_2, VERTEX_TOP,
    VERTEX_2, VERTEX_1, VERTEX_TOP,
    VERTEX_1, VERTEX_0, VERTEX_TOP,
    VERTEX_0, VERTEX_1, VERTEX_2,
};

//doesn't work
std::vector<Vertex> vertexes = {
    VERTEX_0, VERTEX_2, VERTEX_TOP,
    VERTEX_2, VERTEX_1, VERTEX_TOP,
    VERTEX_1, VERTEX_0, VERTEX_TOP,
    VERTEX_0, VERTEX_1, VERTEX_2,
};
```

buffer allocation

```cpp
m_vertex.allocate(vertexes.data(), sizeof(Vertex) * vertexes.size());
```

Comment: What is `m_vertex`? Does `allocate` take the number of bytes?

Comment: Why does `std::vector<Vertex> vertexes = { ... }` not work? Is `Vertex` not copyable? But then `std::array` won't work either.

Comment: Given the nature of the problem it should be quite easy to put together a [mcve].